# How to set jquery event on named function with a keyboard event in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these 3 functions:

```
var triggerWynPopup = function(e) {
    ...
    e.preventDefault();
};

var closeWynPopup = function(e) {
    ...
    e.preventDefault();
};

var closeWynPopupKeyb = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeWynPopup();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

And I am calling them like this:

```
$btClose.on('click', closeWynPopup);
$wynPop.on('click', triggerWynPopup);
$document.on('keyup', closeWynPopupKeyb);
```

It works cool when I do click to call `closeWynPopup` and `triggerWynPopup`, but when I call `$document.on('keyup', closeWynPopupKeyb);` it throws an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

---

What could be the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed passing `e` to `closeWynPopup()` in `closeWynPopupKeyb`

```
var closeWynPopupKeyb = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        closeWynPopup(e); // pass "e" here
    }
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    closeWynPopup(e);  //  here pass 'e'
}
```

As you are passing nothing in `closeWynPopup();` so `e` will undefine in function definition so it is giving an error.

```
if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    closeWynPopup();  // passing undefined(in function e become 'undefined')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

no special event definition is required for the function. you can do it this way.

```js
var closeWynPopupKeyb = function() {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        closeWynPopup(event.keyCode);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
};

var closeWynPopup = function(x) {
    console.log(x);
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", closeWynPopupKeyb);
```